# I can't access my store aftering changing Store URL

Tags: magento-1.7, configuration, core

So, I tried to change my store URL with the following queries:

```
1. SELECT config_id FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url'; (config_id was 6)

2. UPDATE core_config_data SET value = "http://kokorugs.com/store" WHERE config_id = 6;

3. SELECT config_id FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/secure/base_url'; (config_id was 7)

4. UPDATE core_config_data SET value = "http://kokorugs.com/store" WHERE config_id = 7;
```

I do not have SSL.

In an attempt to access my store, I've tried the following:

1. After inputting "online-rug-store" into core_config_data id's 6 & 7, I got this error: "Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted." No 404 redirect error.
2. Going to http://kokorugs.com/store -> Returns 404 error
3. Going to http://kokorugs.com/magento -> Redirects to http://kokorugs.com/store and returns 404 error
4. Resetting core_config_data to "http://kokorugs.com/magento" for config_id's 6 and 7 and trying to visit http://kokorugs.com/magento -> Returns 404 error
5. I have tried clearing cache by deleting contents in var/cache/ and var/session/ and no changes.

Before I reinstall magento and start from scratch, are there any other ideas that I should be trying?

THANK YOU FOR ANY HELP!

Comment: Did you change folder where magento is on your hosting? Is it root folder of your virtual host or what is the path from root folder to magento folder? Check `RewriteBase` directive in .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL of your website is stored in these fields:

1. web/unsecure/base_url
2. web/secure/base_url

If your store URL is `http://example.com/magento/`, Magento will keep this URL in those two fields in `core_config_data` table.

If you move your Magento to another directory, for example:

```
/public_html/magento/ --> /public_html/new_magento/
```

URL of your site will also change:

```
http://example.com/magento/ --> http://example.com/new_magento/
```

So you will need to update entries in `core_config_data` table. Replace old URL with your new URL: `http://example.com/new_magento/`

Comment: Yes, but I have just overwritten these fields and now I can't access my store or admin panel since I have included the wrong syntax. My goal is to try and re-input the defaults and hopefully everything will be back to normal.

Comment: You don't need to go to Magento admin panel. Open your database in phpMyAdmin or whatever you use to manage databases and add your last valid URL to `core_config_data` table.

Comment: That is what I've been doing. But, how do I know if everything is fine? I check by trying to go to my store, and I get 404 errors.

Comment: Your URL has to match current directory in which your Magento is now (after you moved it: `http://example.com/new_magento/`). So maybe you entered incorrect URL. Or enter old URL if you didn't move your Magento: `http://example.com/magento/`

Comment: I tried the old URL as well, and like I said, it redirects to the new URL and returns a 404 error.

Comment: I tried changing the name to http://example.com/store instead of online-rug-store just for change, and after doing that, going to http://example.com/magento/ redirects to http://example.com/store now.

Comment: The magento folder is under the root directory and hasn't been moved

Comment: I did, however, try to rename the magento folder and then named it back to magento

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm lost. :)  Please edit your post and explain what you actually did. Moved Magento to another folder or just changed the URL in database? Please also see my post, I extended it a little bit.

Comment: I appreciate your help anyway.

Comment: Often the problem with mysterious non-changing base urls comes about because of permissions that disallow Magento from writing to its var/cache and var/tmp folders. It establishes a cache subdirectory in the system /tmp/ folder system and uses the configuration cached therein. No amount of deleting cache folders or mucking with core_config_data will fix anything till you get Magento using its proper cache directories.

Comment: @FiascoLabs, I do have a cache still being generated in the var/cache folder after previously deleting it, but my tmp folder is located under var/package/tmp - both of these folders with 777 permissions. It does seem like a permissions problem, however. Do you know of any other folders to check?

Comment: @FiascoLabs, so I got my store back and I am not sure why it worked, but I deleted the url value for the secured url and now my-site.com/magento works. It won't change to another URL but I think I'll give it a rest for now and start making back-ups =)

Comment: @zitix, I have no idea how, but I have access to my store again. Now, I've inputed url values like http://my-site.com/store/ for both unsecured and the secured core_config_data and I can't access my site from my-site.com/store but my-site.com/magento works for some reason. I am very, very confused but grateful nonetheless.

Comment: @FiascoLabs You're a lifesaver!